# How to change the language in HTML using PHP?

Tags: php, localization

I have a simple html site.I want to change the language for that based on the country code
using php.That means i want to localise my site. Or translate the site to the user selected language 
Any one help me with this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: And what about the people visiting Japan or something, that want to use the site in English?  Screw them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend allowing the user to choose their own language. However, you could use something like this:

```
<?php
if (!isset($language)) {      
    $language = explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);      
    $language = strtolower(substr(chop($language[0]),0,2));      
}      
?>
```

`$language` would then contain the language you should display to your user. What you do from there is up to you.

Comment: Can i use this code to change the content of the webpage to the particular language

Comment: You'd do better to use whatever language the client passes headers saying it prefers, at first.  That, at least, lets the user decide what language they want without potentially having to wander through the foreign-language preferences trying to figure out the Russian words for "show me stuff in English, damn it!"  Their browser will almost certainly be set to accept a language the user knows well.  (If it doesn't, then it's misconfigured.)  Use that code, or their preferences once they've picked one, to select a table of localized messages / files a la gettext.

Answer (score 2):

No, that doesn't mean you want to localize your site. It means you're assuming you know what your users want, better than they do. Take a look at [this question and answers](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14127/a-good-solution-how-to-localize-and-let-user-choose-language-on-html-page) on UX.stackexchange.com

The problems with your approach are that you assume that anyone from a country top-level-domain will be wanting to view your site in that countries language. As a commenter already stated; what about foreign speakers abroad? What about certain people who are trying to learn another language and wanting to view content in that language?? What about countries where more than once language is standard? **A country is NOT a language.**

The best option for you to do (if you truly want a localized site) is to allow the user to CHOOSE his or her viewing language.

Allow a dropdown or other method for a user to select their language, and use [PHP's Gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) module to help with your content translation.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend doing this in php at all. I would try using jQuery or javascript.

Or have the language be switched by the user. You would have to use Handlebars or something of that sort to cycle through multiple languages. I would not see writing an entire website 20 times for languages.

http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Using [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) makes multi-language support not nearly as complicated as writing the same site 20 times.  Basically, instead of `<p>foo</p>`, you have `<p><?= _('foo') ?></p>` or the like, and then compile a translations file for each language.  It's not really going to be easier in JS unless you use Google Translate to get a half-assed translation and call that good enough.

Answer (score 0):

1-create a class with php like this

```
class Language
{
function __construct($lan)
{
    require_once($lan . '.php');
}

}
```

2-create files like en.php or jp.php an then in each lang files use class variables (en.php):

```
   $this->firstpage="HOME";
   $this->login="LOGIN";
```

3-use class in main page

```
    $language = new language($_POST["language"]);
```

4-use php variables in content like this

```
   <a href=""> <?php $language->firstpage; ?> </a>
```

for little sites this is a good way to use php for change language;